# Unity C# raycasting from center of an object to find mesh intersection

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a respawn system for a game in unity that starts the character back on the last platform they were on.

As it is currently, it keeps track of which platform they were last grounded on with onCollisionEnter and detects if onCollisionExit touches an out of bounds area.

I need to find the position of a face on the mesh with the y axis (assuming the best way is to do a raycast on the global y axis from the center of the platform) and add the height of the character/2 to determine where to respawn the character.

I'm very new to unity and c#, so I've never done a raycast before and I'm not sure if it's possible to raycast from inside an object to find it's mesh in a given direction, or if there is a better/more efficient way.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: i dont know unity, but could you try placing the player at ever higher heights until there is no collision?

Comment: This might actually work if I use an empty object, and then instantiate the character at the empty. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

"if it's possible to raycast from inside an object to find it's mesh in a given direction"

You can place a empty gameobject at the center of your mesh (make it child of your mesh ) then pass the position of this empty gameobject to raycast origin.

I usually make re-spawn system with triggers. If you explain little bit more what actually you want to do. I'll try to guide you in that particular direction.

Comment: I want to respawn the player in the center of the last platform they were grounded on (collision of less than 60 degrees). So if they jump and miss, they don't have to re-do a bunch of stuff.

The platforms though, aren't going to be flat, so I need it to automatically figure out the position of the center of the mesh on the y axis and spawn the character a little above that.

Comment: one way of doing this is that you have to create a empty game object at the position where you want to respawn your character for each platform. And pass its reference to the platform script file (script in which you already repawing your character). So when you're respawing your character get the position of the empty game object from its reference and place you character accordingly.

Comment: Actually, the system I already have stores which platform that the character last walked on in a variable. The problem is not respawning the character(I'm just going to change the transform of the player directly), the problem is finding the position of the mesh relative to the center of the platform on a specific axis(y).

Comment: Basically the problem I'm trying to solve is where to put the empty, or where to respawn the character. I need some way of finding the position of the platforms mesh on the y axis relative to the center of the platform. So the center of the platform gives me x, y, and z coords for a point in space, then from that point I move up on the Y until I'm no longer inside the mesh. And I add to that value, the height of my character. Then I would have x, y, and z coords with which I can easily respawn my character. I just don't know how to find the position of the platforms mesh.